# How do we Enter Global IT Market Global Market like the USA, Europe or Australia

Tags: marketing, business-plan, information-technology, foreign-markets

I am based on south Asia and I am doing freelancing service through Fiverr. Currently I am expanding my services with professional Team. But I have no idea about entering to Global Market. My requirement is entering to global market directly. I don't need to follow or pay for freelancing web site such as fiverr or upwork.

Can someone explain how to enter to global market? How to contact directly global companies for my services?

Comment: See https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/10072/26181 . In your case, you might need to hire a top notch sales person who can travel to those companies and have booths at the trade shows those companies go to.